# Which GUI control is suitable for this purpose?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using winforms of .NET & C#. I'm developing a medical software. I need to implement "Patient History". When doctor enters the PatientID. All the previous appointment dates will be displayed in a side panel. These entries will dynamically fetched from the database. Interface will be more or less similar to Histroy in web browser. Except that I'm not going to  use tree control and categorize entries into 'today' 'yesterday' 'older than 7 days' 'last week' etc..

What controls do I need to use. I'm not clear about this. If you have any better idea. Please  mention.

Answer (score 5):

Try a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Well you have given the answer yourself I think: a TreeView?

Comment: +1 sometimes just talking out your problem can give you the answer

Comment: @Gerrie: The op says, *`Except that I'm not going to use tree control`*

Comment: But a tree control is perfectly suited for that situation IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I used a page like this

```
   .......................................................................
   .                                                                     .
   .       Doctor Entry for patient ID (search box)                      .
   .                                                                     .
   .......................................................................
   .                                  .                                  .
   .                                  .                                  .
   .     Patient Picture              .     patient Info (most on Label) .
   .                                  .                                  .
   .                                  .                                  .
   .......................................................................
   .                                                                     .
   .                                                                     .
   .                                                                     .
   .                    Patient History Only In GridView                 .
   .                 (which Customized as well as Possible)              .
   .                                                                     .
   .......................................................................
```

Answer (score 0):

Most common control for that is the GridView

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a few different ideas given so far. How about mocking out each the ideas  (on paper, or code if you've got time) and try to get a feel for which works best for you.